# In Navigation 2.5.3 version, add is used to replace the replace method. When switching fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

For example, I added 5 fragments to my navigation and called them A, B, C, D, and E separately. Among them, A is the root node. When switching to B, A will not flash. When switching to C, D, and E, the layout file of A will first flash, and then jump to C, D, E. I try The problem with reading the source code seems to be that there is a problem with the last few lines of code in the addEntryToBackStack method when calling the navigate(node:NavDestination,args:Bundle?,navOptions: NavOptions?,navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras?) method in the NavController file, but I Without any clue to find the problem, we can only keep adding breakpoints to the code to observe where they may be abnormal

Comment: I solved the problem. This is due to the problem of the transition animation set when the fragment is added